Activities not showing up to related custom object
I have an issue related to Activities. In my Opportunity records, I am creating a task (Log a call) so I can monitor the calls I do. However, those task records are not showing up in the record that is related to any Opp object. See images below for reference:


In the first picture, you'll see here an Opp record wherein I create my Log a Call task records. In the second picture, this is a record from a custom object related to the Opp record however, you can see that the Activity History is empty.
I already confirmed that the Allow Activities is checked for the custom object. All of your insights will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Do you mean that you have created activity records for the custom object 'Application' but you are not able to see? or you are expecting Activities from opportunity to appear under activity tab of 'Application'?

Originally, I am creating the task records under Opportunity records and as per my understanding, those task records should appear under the custom object "Application" activity history as it is related to an Opportunity. Is this possible?

Only activities related to an application appear over your second screenshot and not the activities related to Opportunity if the related to field value is not explicitly changed by user.
Basically, if you are looking at a record 'Application - A' then only a activities related to 'Application - A' will appear on the screen under Activity.

My apologies as I am kind of confused. Let me reiterate what I said. So my goal is to make sure that the created Tasks under Opportunity records will appear too under Application records'  Activity history. Note that the Application object is a custom object.
On the first screenshot, that's an Opportunity record wherein I created Task records. The second screenshot is an Application record related via Lookup to the Opportunity record. The issue is the created task record under Opportunity records is not showing under Application record's Activity History.

activity records show up based on Related To field value. In this case if the 'Related To' is populated with your application record's Id then it should appear else no. When you are creating task under opportunity, choose 'Related To' field as Application record by default it will take Opportunity as 'Related To'.

To confirm, the created task records under Opportunity won't appear under Application record which is from a custom object? Is that correct?

check the "Related To" field value of the task records created. Is it having related to field value as Opportunity Id or Application Id?.

It's opportunity as I am logging the call in an Opp record. It seems what I want to happen is impossible. Even though there's an application record related to the Opp record via Look up, the activities I logged will not appear in the Application record's Activity History
